# Clearing echo text on page refresh

Tags: php

I am designing an image file upload page for a website and, on Submit, the script echoes an 'Upload Successful' message. That all works fine.

My problem is that once the success message is on the page, it won't go away! If the user wants to upload another file, I want him to be able to refresh the page and get rid of the echoed message. I can't understand why that doesn't happen by default but can anyone explain how I make that happen?

Mike

Comment: Show your code.  You're likely echoing it even if no file is uploaded (or the refresh is uploading the file again.)

Comment: Need to see the code. If you have some variable that triggers echoing success message, maybe you should set that variable to NULL at the beginning of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways I can think of doing what you want.

First, put a link back to the upload script underneath your upload successful text.

```
echo '<h3>Upload Successful</h3>';
echo '<a href="upload_script.php">Upload another file</a>';
```

The second way involves sending a refresh header which will redirect to the upload page after a few seconds.

```
header( "refresh:3;url=upload_script.php" );
echo '<h3>Upload Successful</h3>';
```

This will redirect to the upload page after 3 seconds. header() must be called before your script outputs (echo) anything to the page.

Comment: Oh dear - that simple! I assumed it wouldn't work because I thought the browser refresh button did the same thing. But I tested your suggestion and it worked like a charm. Many thanks and sorry to be such a twit.